# How to remove elements from List all elements that are not in the ascending order?

Tags: list, sorting, python-zip

I'm novice in Python and I have a question.

part 1
How to remove elements from List all elements that are not in the ascending order?
Pls make with function.

Input: list1 = [2, 99, 3, 5, 6, 10, 8, 11, 22]
Output : new_list [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 11, 22]

part 2
How to move the out of order elements to other list?
Pls make with function.

Input: list1 = [2, 99, 3, 5, 6, 10, 8, 11, 22]
Output : new_list [99, 8]

My release are following:

```
list_1 = [2, 4, 3, 5, 33, 6, 10, 8, 11, 22]
def eliminate_element(li):
    return [list_1[0]] + [j for i, j in zip(list_1, list_1[1:]) if i < j]
print(eliminate_element(list_1))
```

Comment: SO is not a coding service, so you'lll need to show some attempt (code). These are very basic problems. Furthermore please format your code SO provides when you post/edit your question

Comment: Why is 22 not in the new list in part 1?

Comment: @Soleil : Please correct my code for receive correct answer from function. Or which other functions I can use for this task ?

Comment: @theherk : you right, I'd corrected new list in part1

Comment: Why do you blame 99 when 3 is the one that's not ascending? Output for part 1 should be [2, 99].

Comment: @KellyBundy , 
I see 'correct' ascending order [2, 9, 3, 5, 6, 10, 11, 22] with extra items here [99, 10]. Output : new_list [2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 11, 22].

Comment: Define "correct".

Answer (score -2):

You can do these both in one step. This is quite a verbose way to do it, but it should help. Basically, you want two new lists.

```py
l = [2, 4, 3, 5, 33, 6, 10, 8, 11, 22]

ordered = []
unordered = []

high = 0
for item in l:
    if item >= high:
        ordered.append(item)
        high = item
    else:
        unordered.append(item)

print(ordered)
print(unordered)
```

which yields:

```
[2, 4, 5, 33]
[3, 6, 10, 8, 11, 22]
```

Comment: [2, 4, 3, 5, 33, 6, 10, 8, 11, 22] - here only '33' and '8' elements that are not in the ascending order...

Comment: @Pit, are you suggesting 3 comes after 4? I don't think so.